# angular-markdown-directive not displaying content as HTML

Tags: angularjs, markdown, showdown

I'm trying to get [angular-markdown-directive](https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive) working in my Angular app but I've had no success yet.

I've followed all the instructions (included sanitize, showdown and markdown etc) and added:

```
<btf-markdown>
  #Markdown directive
  *It works!*
</btf-markdown>
```

into my page but the markdown renders as it is, not as HTML.

I've included the scripts too;

```
<script src='/bower_components/showdown/src/showdown.js'></script>
<script src='/bower_components/angular-markdown-directive/markdown.js'></script>
```

and the module `btford.markdown`

There are no errors in my console either so I'm really unsure what the issue could be - I'm hoping someone else has some advice on this matter.

My version of markdown is 0.3.1

Comment: You have included the scripts as well imported the modules?

Comment: Yes I have - will add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time `<btf-markdown>` directive is not working as expected. I face the same issue while using this and finally move on and create my own directive for it.

[Here is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bYgS0rp4qDLEpoes8Skz?p=preview)

it working fine for me and hope also for you.

> Don't forgot to add showdown lib

[ShowDown lib](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the official [angular-showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/ng-showdown) integration lib.

The angular-markdown-directive lib uses an outdated version of showdown which might explain why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [angular-marked](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked) in my angular app and it works very well. had a little bit of trouble with adding "target='_blank'" attribute to my links in the marked down text. turns out they have a very convenient config for that. hope it comes handy for you